# argc and argv aren't running

Tags: c, linux, pid

I'm trying to run this code under Ubuntu, but when I run the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc , char agrv[3]){
  int pid ,sig;
  sig = atoi( argv[1]);
  pid = atoi( argv[2]);
  kill(pid,sig);
  return(0);
}
```

It says that

```
ex02.c:10:13: error: ‘argv’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 sig = atoi( argv[1]);
```

Comment: Correct declaration is `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` `argv` is not an array of char, but an array of char pointer.

Comment: script? Ubunto?? really???

Comment: and further, `argv` and `agrv` are different names - you've used both.

Comment: I addition to @LPs comment: Have a close look at the parameter declaration of **`argv`**. Computers are not forgiving. Don't use sloppy syntax. And also format&indent your code properly.

Comment: What exactly does this Ubunto <== funny. You mean Ubuntu?

Comment: Semantics are important - you aren't running the above code, you are compiling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo with `agrv` and the signature for main is `int main(int argv, char *argv[])`.

`argv` is an array of `char *` terminated with `NULL`. Each element of the array up to the `NULL` represents a string from your command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int pid, sig;
  sig = atoi(argv[1]);
  pid = atoi(argv[2]);
  kill(pid, sig);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: **Strings**....please not again :|

Comment: Hey, come on, it's a C-string.

Comment: There are no strings in C.

Answer (score 2):

you made mistake in definition line of `main`, `argv` is the array of `char*` strings

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/*
other code here
*/

}
```

Comment: ... is the array of _pointers to `char`_ will probably be better.

Comment: There are no array of char* Strings I'm c.

Comment: Thank you guys , I really feel stupid right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the function header of your `main()`.

It should be like this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Function Body
    return 0;
}
```

The Formal parameter argv is an `array of pointers to char`. And each pointer to char holds an argument passed to the program (Also, the name of the program will be pointed by argv[0]).